# How to track the state or activity on the app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am making an ipad app and i want that when user performs any activity in app it must be recored or stored like in my app there are video and catalogues so if user open videos section and watches any video that should be stored as user watched video at this and then move to catalog etc like this any idea how to implement this thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sqlite or coredata to save the name of videos watched by user.
You can add a record to your table(watchedVideo table)when user clicks on a particular video from videos list.

And then show the list of video in table(watchedVideo table) in ur catalogue screen.

Comment: its just video i know we can do this what about other things mean what evere screen he visits or button clicks all should be recorded